# Как вытащить значение src у картинки?

Tags: php

Как вытащить значение src у картинки?

Comment: Почитайте про регулярные выражения.

Comment: А можно сылочку или название этого выражения

Comment: @cas-live, "регулярные выражения".

Comment: оч смешно их много

Comment: @cas-live ваша лень не знает границ, `/src=['"]([^"']+)['"]/`